# Sending a List of Byte Array as response

Tags: arrays, spring-boot, rest, httpresponse

I am using SpringBoot for my restful web service and for one of the end points I am sending a ByteArray as response which works perfectly as it uses ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.

But now I want to send List of ByteArray in response but it fails as it is not able to find suitable Message converter.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved.

Below is snippet of code for End Point. If I return just byte array instead of list then it works but when I try to return list of byte array then it fails as it cannot find Message converter:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/payloadList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<byte[]>> loadPayload(@RequestParam(value = "tradeIds", required = false) List<String> tradeIds,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "clientName", required = false) String clientName) throws SQLException, IOException {
    LOG.info(String.format("Fetching generic trade details for client : {%s} and trade id : {%s}", clientName, Arrays.toString(tradeIds.toArray())));
    tradeIds.forEach(tradeId->validateRequestParams(tradeId, clientName));
    List<byte[]> payload = tradeLoadService.loadPayload(clientName,tradeIds);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<byte[]>> (payload, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Please tell us why do you want to do so? What's your use case?

Comment: Added code snippet.

Comment: I do not see an issue, body: `byte[] b = "Hello".getBytes();
        List<byte[]> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(b); return ResponseEntity.ok(l);`  I get a response: `["SGVsbG8="]` I suspect issue may be with `tradeLoadService.loadPayload(clientName,tradeIds)`

Comment: issue is with the `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);`

Comment: Thanks @dkb , what should be the content type for list of byte array then ?

Comment: If you need to use OCTET stream then I would suggest to use `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE` in RequestMapping, but client needs to use the same to receive it, else it will not work.

Comment: But if client is consuming and expecting as Json then I would suggest updating code to `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Comment: What is the content of the byte[] in the list?

Comment: @dkb basically I want to send a Java Object which has a byte array inside in, if I use MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON type then web service responds fine but at client end, it fails as it cannot find a suitable message converter.

Comment: I tried invoking the endpoint (returning java object with byte array inside) from postman as well as spring boot client and it works fine with APPLICATION_JSON content type. 
`Result result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:20600/payload", Result.class); System.out.println(result.getResult());` - This prints list of byte array